# Why am I getting different integers for these two print statements?

Tags: c

I was tinkering around with C char pointers and wanted some clarity on some tests I was doing.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    char* string0 = "hello";
    printf("%d\n", string0);
    printf("%d", &string0);

    return 0;
}
```

The outputs I get are different integers (4214852 and 6422300 respectively). What do the two printed integers mean? From my understanding, &string0 retrieves the address of string0, but I also made a char pointer string0 point to "hello", so won't string0 also hold the address of the pointer? So shouldn't the two prints be the same?

Comment: Pointers are variables and have their own addresses too

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`string0` is the address of the string `"hello"`.

`&string0` is the address of the variable `string0` itself.

These two things are different (the string is not the variable), so their addresses should be different.

By the way, passing pointers to `%d` invokes *undefined behavior* because `%d` is for printing `int`. You should cast pointers to `void*` and use `%p` to print pointers via `printf()`.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    char* string0 = "hello";
    printf("%p\n", (void*) string0);
    printf("%p", (void*) &string0);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: why cast to (void*) ? I did not understood.

Comment: Because [the specification](http://chimera.roma1.infn.it/SP/COMMON/iso-iec-9899-1990.pdf) says that `void*` should be passed for `%p`.

Answer (score 0):

Sticking with the output of your code (`4214852` and `6422300`), memory layout of the process at runtime is somewhat like below:

```
memory address     value
4214850            unknown (not relevant)
4214852            'h'
4214853            'e'
4214854            'l'
4214855            'l'
4214856            'o'
4214857            0 (value zero which corresponds to '\0')
...
...
...
6422300            4214852 (starting address of 'hello')
```

Answer (score 0):

Now you will have the same numbers

```
int main() {
    char string0[] = "hello";
    printf("%ld\n", (long)string0);
    printf("%ld", (long)&string0);

    return 0;
}
```